# Can concepts replace all other instances of the template keyword?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, c++17, c++-concepts

Can C++ concepts be used to replace all appearances of the keyword `template`
(apart from the concept's own declaration)?

I'm curious if there is any reason one would still need to use the keyword `template` for other language constructs such as templated classes or templated functions.  The only exception I can think of, are templated type aliases.  Using templates for compile time calculations would be replaceable through `constexpr` functions.

To keep my question brief,
What can regular template declarations do,  that the adoption of concepts + constexpr can't replace?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by concepts, e.g. by providing a link to the respective working draft?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your premise is a bit loaded. While it is *possible* to transform the old syntax for templates (for function, class, variable, or alias templates all alike) by a concept introduction, in many cases doing so is artificial and passes the baton. Take the classic `std::transform` function template as an example:

```
// current
template<typename In, typename Out, typename Func>
Out transform(In first, In last, Out out, Func func);
```

You can transform it to use a concept introduction instead in a very obvious manner as such:

```
TransformParameters{In, Out, Func}
Out transform(In first, In last, Out out, Func func);
```

As you can tell this is fairly mechanical, and also pointless: what are the odds that the `TransformParameters` pseudo-concept would be reusable anywhere else, and how would it help the programmer in any way? This declaration would give you *no* new information over the old one. I’ll grant you that, assuming this pseudo-concept is correctly written, the programmer should benefit from improved diagnostics/overload resolution.

Instead, I would expect a sensible, concept-enabled declaration of `std::transform` to look as such (because we have no standard concepts yet I’m using fictive concepts and traits here, focus on the principle):

```
template<Iterator In, Iterator Out, Value Func>
    requires
        Callable<Func, iterator_reference_t<In>>
        && AssignableFrom<
            iterator_reference_t<Out>,
            result_of_t<Func(iterator_reference_t<In>)>
        >
Out transform(In first, In last, Out out, Func func);
```

The idea being the requirements reflect the fact that `std::transform` has the associated expression `*out = func(*in)` . In addition, the elements that appear in the requires-clauses are certainly reusable (the iterator reference type and `std::result_of_t` being indeed already in use).

This relatively simple example shows why concept introduction simply won’t work everywhere. Some of the require elements involve what I would like to call third-party types, namely `iterator_reference_t<…>` and `result_of_t<…>`, while some input types are involved in several relations at once (e.g. `It` appears in `Iterator` and `Callable`).

Otherwise, i.e. when there’s exactly one relation between all the argument types and only them, and if that relation is reasonably expressive of intent and preferably reusable; then concept introductions might have their place. (An abbreviated template with a concept introduction widens this field of application a tiny bit more though.)

Comment: but given concepts `Input_iterator`, `Output_iterator` and `Unary_function`   for which the TS would define the `requires` clause, `template<Input_iterator It, Output_iterator Out, Unary_function Fun> transform(It first, It last, Fun fun);` would be net win, no?

Comment: @TemplateRex I don’t follow. That still uses the `template` keyword and doesn’t capture the full constraints of `std::transform`, which is my necessary to my argument. Remember: it’s the principle that matters, not the exact concepts.

Answer (score 6):

`template` would still be required for explicit instantiations

```
template some_class<int>;
```

and disambiguating dependent member templates

```
obj.template fun<T>();
```